# Joint PDF or CDF of two dependent random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, conditional-probability

Assume random variable $N$ with a pdf of $f\left(N\right)$ and CDF of $F\left(N\right)$. Accordingly, the other two random variables $X$ and $Y$ are defined based on $N$ so that $X=\alpha N$ and $Y=\left(1-\alpha \right)N$, where $0<\alpha <1$. I need to find the joint probability function of $X$ and $Y,$ knowing that they are not independent. So, I tried the following calculations. Is it correct?

$$\begin{align}F_{X,Y}\left(s,t\right) &=\Pr\left(X\le s,Y\le t\right)\\&=\Pr\left(X\le s\right)\cdot \Pr\left(Y\le t\mid X\le s\right)\\&=\Pr\left(\alpha N\le s\right)\cdot \Pr\left(\left(1-\alpha \right)N\le t\mid \alpha N\le s\right)\\&=\Pr\left(N\le \frac{s}{\alpha }\right)\cdot \Pr\left(\left.N\le \frac{t}{1-\alpha }\right|N\le \frac{s}{\alpha }\right)\end{align}$$

If $\dfrac{s}{\alpha }\le \dfrac{t}{1-\alpha }$, $\Pr\left(\left.N\le \dfrac{t}{1-\alpha }\right|N\le \dfrac{s}{\alpha }\right)=1$ and consequently $F_{X,Y}\left(s,t\right)=\Pr\left(N\le \dfrac{s}{\alpha }\right)=F_X\left(\dfrac{s}{\alpha }\right)$

Otherwise, $F_{X,Y}\left(s,t\right)=F_X\left(\dfrac{s}{\alpha }\right).\dfrac{F_Y\left(\frac{t}{1-\alpha }\right)}{F_Y\left(\frac{s}{\alpha }\right)}$.

Please advise.

Comment: $F_{X,Y}(s,t) = \mathbf{P}(N \leq \min(\frac{s}{\alpha}, \frac{t}{1 - \alpha})) = F_N(\min(\frac{s}{\alpha}, \frac{t}{1 - \alpha})).$

Comment: @WilliamM. Thanks a million! This looks quite correct, interestingly simple and practical! Thanks again!

Comment: @WilliamM. We can we say that

$F_{X,Y}\left(s,t\right)=\left\{ \begin{array}{c}
\frac{s}{\alpha }<\frac{t}{1-\alpha };F_{X,Y}\left(s,t\right)=F_N\left(\frac{s}{\alpha }\right) \\ 
\frac{s}{\alpha }>\frac{t}{1-\alpha };F_{X,Y}\left(s,t\right)=F_N\left(\frac{t}{1-\alpha }\right) \end{array}
\right.$

Therefore, we should be able to calculate 

$f_{X,Y}\left(s,t\right)=\frac{{\partial}^2F_{X,Y}\left(s,t\right)}{\partial s\partial t}$. 

But for both situations, it yields zero! Would you please advise where I am making a mistake?

Comment: A random vector $X$ in $\mathbf{R}^d$ such that $\mathbf{P}(X \in \mathrm{V}) = 1,$ where $\mathrm{V}$ is a vector subspace (or more generally, a manifold) of dimension $\leq d-1,$ __cannot__ have a density.